# Bootstrap 5: trying to get a border-right to extend to bottom of Card

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a two-column page using Cards, where the cards extend to the bottom of the page.   This part is working fine.

Inside the right-hand Card are two Columns.  The first column has a border along the right edge to visually separate the two.

Regardless of the height of the content inside the column, I want the border to extend to the bottom of the parent Card.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-2 " style=" height: calc(100vh - 7.5rem); ">
                        <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                            Menu items
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-2 " style=" height: calc(100vh - 7.5rem); ">
                        <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2 flex-fill" style="border-right: 1px solid black;">
                                    first column - the border line should extend to the bottom of the parent card
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-10 flex-fill">
                                    second column
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

Use pseudo element `::before`, see the snippet below.

```css
.left_border::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(100% - 32px); /* padding-top is 16px and padding-bottom is 16px (2 * 16px = 32px). */
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-2 " style=" height: calc(100vh - 7.5rem); ">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
      Menu items
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-2 " style=" height: calc(100vh - 7.5rem); ">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 flex-fill">
          first column - the border line should extend to the bottom of the parent card
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 flex-fill left_border">
          <div class="ms-3">
            second column
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

border right will only span the width or height of the element its applied to. Try inserting a hr element in between the columns or at the end/start of the 2.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_vertical_line.asp